# Implementing an interface that requires a Task return type in synchronous code

Tags: c#

When implementing an interface method that returns a `Task<T>` with synchronous code you can use the `Task.FromResult<T>(result)`. When the result is just `Task` is there a better option than using something like `Task.FromResult<object>(null);`?

Comment: Could you not just use `await` or `.Wait()`?

Comment: @ShaunWilde I don't want the overhead of an async method. (Take a look at the IL doing this generates.)

Comment: Using `Task.FromResult` to create a completed task and upcasting it to the non-generic `Task` is about as elegant as it gets unfortunately. Personally I'd stick with that and cache a single instance of a completed `Task` in a static field somewhere and keep reusing it.

Comment: `Task.FromResult(0)` is a bit shorter, but essentially the same.

Comment: Nowadays we have `Task.CompletedTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: now there's [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.7.2) as of .NET 4.6.

Comment: Changing the accepted answer as the correct answer has changed

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is no.

A `Task` is a 'wrap' of an action which could be a lambda or delegate. So if you want your method return a `Task` object then you need instantiate a `Task` instance or retrieve it from some where else.

To instantiate a `Task` instance you have 2 approaches - either use constructor or some factory methods. As mentioned, `Tasks` wraps an action, so you need provide an action in calling the constructor

```
static Task GetTask() 
{
    return new Task(() => { });
}
```

Or if you want your `Task` have a return value, you could do as below

```
static Task GetTask() 
{
    return new Task<object>(() => null);
}
```

The other approach is to use a factory method for creating such a `Task`. Both `Task.Factory` and `Task<T>.FromResult` are the factory methods, but none of both has any better option than you specified.

So again, for creating a new instance you do need to call the constructor which may have some required arguments; or you use some provided factory methods. If you found none of them is convenient, I believe a customized factory/helper is your solution.

By the way, based on C# type inferring, if you return type is a concrete type such as integer, you could do your code as below by omitting the type which is simple enough already:

```
static Task GetTask() 
{
    return Task.FromResult(123);
}
```

As you example is to return `null`, so the type can not be inferred thus you need specify it (object) in you code.